# using different graphics card per application, SLI bridge connected turned off in control panel

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I am often forced to turn off SLI for certain applications to properly run, one of which for example is a racing game that flickers heavily with it on (I also use a oculus dk2 with that game, which is sickening if that happens)

This, however, frees up my second nvidia gtx 960 card, and I was wondering if I would be able to launch an different application on that specific card to make use of it for doing other tasks?

For example, I'm running Firestorm to log into second life, a situation I find myself turning to my second monitor a lot to for example run a YouTube video, which sometimes when running firestorm on the second monitor without any CPU stepping to cause that video to start misbehaving sometimes.

Would it with some heavy tweaks be possible to run Firefox on the second graphics card and make use of that to fix that issue
(even though this is just an example situation, I have confirmed it through testing that it is the graphics card-load that causes these issues)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of tying application (other than OPenGL/CUDA/... etc style) appls to specific graphics cards, but with SLI turned off you can connect one monitor to one graphics card (and game on that) while connecting a second monitor to a port on the other graphics card. (E.g. to watch a movie or to display a game related chat).

This requires you to connect both monitors to the different cards. (Unlike SLI where you needed all outputs on the primary card).

Comment: thank you for your answer, I was wondering, would switching my second monitor to my second card make the graphical processing happen on that card to?

Comment: In aq normal setup (read: no Crossfire, SLI, optimus, no switchable graphics) the calculations are done on the same card which outputs the signal. So yes, the calculation would be done on that card.

Comment: That would probably help your SL performance too, as OpenGL support on a second monitor attached to primary card is never as good as the first monitor. [In another life, I work for Firestorm support ;)

Comment: am a beta tester myself hehe, thanks for your answere, I will look into this and weigh the positives and negatives against each other again.

I can to some extend at least use SLI with SL to.., although the performance gain is minimal.., I do get free AA and AF ^^